# form submit not working on mobile device (match the requested format)

Tags: html, angular

I have a small angular app I have made that works fine on my computer, but does not work properly on any mobile device. The problem is the form submit button. The button will not submit form and hitting the return key on my ipad on the last form field directs back to the card number form field and says "Match the requested format" ... I am using Stripe by the way.

I have tried ngSubmit on the form and changed the button around to input type and type button and etc. I have also got rid of ngSubmit and used (click)="buy()" which also works on a desktop, but not on a mobile device. I have even added (tap) from hammerjs just in case it was a touch issue. I tried using a label outside of the form linked to the submit button. None of which work. I added an alert to just see if the button was even being clicked, and it is, the mobile device will show the alert, but wont submit the form. So, please ignore the the code at the bottom where I have multiple buttons a labels, it was for testing purposes (it all works on desktop though as is, just not on any mobile device).

Here are two pics of the problem:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18grWfXyQN9gvcuJRuUqIoS_yjMsU1vii/view?usp=sharing)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ezhyAtTg1Z1OomLd9pv47Bif-0ILOR5b/view?usp=sharing

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div class="container">
    <form class="example-form" action="#" [formGroup]="stripeTest">
        <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width media-width">
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Full Name"
                               formControlName="name" id="firstName">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('name', 'required')">First Name is
                            required
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>


        </table>
        <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
            <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Phone "
                           formControlName="phone" id="phone">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('phone', 'required')">Zip is
                        required
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
            <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Email"
                           formControlName="email" id="email">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('email', 'required')">Zip is
                        required
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
        </table>

        <p>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width addr-media-width">
          <textarea matInput type="text" placeholder="Address"
                    formControlName="address_line1" id="address"></textarea>
                <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('address_line1', 'required')">Address
                    is required
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="City"
                               formControlName="address_city" id="city">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('address_city', 'required')">City is
                            required
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width state-width">
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="State"
                               formControlName="address_state" id="state">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('address_state', 'required')">State is
                            required
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="half-width">
                        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Zip"
                               formControlName="address_zip" id="zip">
                        <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('address_zip', 'required')">Zip is
                            required
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <input type="submit" id="submit-form" [disabled]="!stripeTest.valid"
                   class="btn btn-danger" style="visibility: hidden" (click)="buy()">
            <button type="button" (tap)="buy()">Buy</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>

        </div>
    </form>

    <label for="submit-form" tabindex="0">Submit</label>
```

buy function

```
buy(){
    const name = this.stripeTest.get('name').value;
    const phone = this.stripeTest.get('phone').value;
    const email = this.stripeTest.get('email').value;
    const address_state = this.stripeTest.get('address_state').value;
    const address_city = this.stripeTest.get('address_city').value;
    const address_line1 = this.stripeTest.get('address_line1').value;
    const address_zip = this.stripeTest.get('address_zip').value;

    let newCustomer: Customer = {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email
    };

    this.dataService.addCustomer(newCustomer)
        .subscribe(() => {
            console.log('Added');
        })

    this.stripeService
        .createToken(this.card, {
            name, address_state, address_city, address_line1,
            address_zip
        })
        .subscribe(obj => {
            if (obj) {
                console.log('Token is --> ', obj.token.id);

                // tslint:disable-next-line: no-unused-expression
                this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/payme', {
                    token: obj.token.id,
                    receipt_email: email
                }).subscribe(
                    (res) => {
                        console.log('The response from server is ', res);
                        console.log('Payment Done');
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/thank-you');
                        alert(obj.token.id + obj + Customer + name + res);
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        console.log('The error is ', err);
                        alert(err);
                    })

            } else {
                // Error creating the token
                console.log('Error comes ');
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: <button type="button" (click)="buy()">Buy</button> should work. Can you put an "alert(1)" or something to test, if the buy() function gets called? Also, as it's inside a form, change type to type="submit"  instead of a "button".

Comment: <button type="submit" id="submit-form" [disabled]="!stripeTest.valid" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="buy()">Buy</button> is my button now. I also tried getting rid of the (click)="buy()" and putting it in the <form (submit)="buy()" ... both worked on the desktop, both failed on the iPad. I added an alert. The alert for the desktop shows the token, class Customer, and name, which is what I had asked the alert to display. On the iPad it just shows [object Object]. It isnt getting the token, or the customer or anything.

Comment: what is the name and version of the browser you are using on the desktop and on the ipad?

Comment: Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) chrome on desktop and 76.0.03809.81 chrome on iPad and Safari on iPad I'm not sure.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the buy function, if that would make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, I feel like a moron. Jeez, shoot me haha. So, the this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/payme') needed to be just this.http.post(/payme) and needed to make changes in the data service as well, getting rid of the localhost:3000 part and just leaving the /add-customer. Wow, I can not believe I did not even see that! Wow. But it still worked on my computer even when deploying to Heroku. I guess because it was on my computer?